# Why must I use float instead of int in this code?

Tags: c

If a type is integer, the result of sum is 0, why?

```
main(){
    int n,s=0;
    float a;
    printf("Input a integer number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while(a!=0){
        a=n%10;
        s=s+a;
        n=n/10;
    }
    printf("Sum: %d",s);
    getch();
}
```

Sorry for my English, thanks you very much!
Can you tell me what is the name of this in english: Ex: "12345" is a number, so what is the name of "1,2,3,4,5"?

Comment: `float a;` initialize to nonzero. E.g `float a = -1.0f;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Yes I know that, but in this code, why must i use float instead of integer?

Comment: It seems that we should use an integer rather. `int a = -1;`

Comment: @someuser Sorry I don't understand :(

Comment: That `a` is refers to the value not initialized is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are calculating the sum of the digits that make up a number.

The problem is that you fail to initialize `a`. If it happens to get the initial value of `0`, the code in the while loop will never execute.

Also, the condition is wrong, you shoud test on `n` instead. Consider what will happen if you enter `101`. Your current code will stop then it reaches the `0` and will output a sum of `1` instead of `2`.

So, if we fix the issues:

```
int main() {
    int n,s=0;
    int a;
    printf("Input a integer number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while (n!=0) {
        a=n%10;
        s=s+a;
        n=n/10;
    }
    printf("Sum: %d",s);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```